# ExtJS 5: All stores are updated when changing a single store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a tabpanel, with images as titles, and a custom component as html. Those custom components use stores, but I'm having an error when updating a single variable (status), all the variables change. Here I show the code:

SelectableButtons component:

```
Ext.require('Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore');

/**
 * Selectable button with image
 */
Ext.define('Cat3.view.fsm.components.SelectableButtons', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.View',
    cls: 'selectable-buttons',
    alias: 'widget.selectable-buttons',
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="thumb-wrap button button-{status}">',
                '<img src="resources/images/cards/{type}/{status}/{name}.png">',
                '<img src="resources/images/icons/icon_mandatory.png" class="button-tick button-tick-{status}">',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],

    // Set both to false if you want single select
    multiSelect: true,
    simpleSelect: true,

    trackOver: false,
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    listeners: {
        select: function(ths, record, eOpts) {
            record.set('status', 'active');
            debugAmenaButtonStatus(this);
        },
        deselect: function(ths, record, eOpts) {
            record.set('status', 'passive');
        },
        selectionchange: function(selection) {
            this.refresh();
        },
        containerclick: function(ths, e, eOpts) {
            return false; // Stops the deselection of items
        }
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore');
        this.setStore(store);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});


debugAmenaButtonStatus = function(ref) {
    ref.up().up().items.items.forEach(function(tab) { // Tab
        console.log(tab.items.items[0].getStore().data.items[0].data.status); // Amena Button Status
    });
};
```

SelectableButtonsCarousel component (Tab panel). It uses another store but it isn't related:

```
var cardsImagePath = 'resources/images/cards/';

var ImageModel = Ext.define('ImageModel2', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'type',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        type: 'string'
    }, ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'ImageModel2',
    data: [{
        name: 'amena',
        type: 'operator',
    }, {
        name: 'movistar',
        type: 'operator',
    }, {
        name: 'orange',
        type: 'operator',
    }, {
        name: 'simyo',
        type: 'operator',
    }, {
        name: 'yoigo',
        type: 'operator',
    }, {
        name: 'vodafone',
        type: 'operator',
    }]
});


Ext.define('Cat3.view.fsm.components.SelectableButtonsCarousel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'basic-tabs',
    cls: 'selectable-buttons-carousel',
    alias: 'widget.selectable-buttons-carousel',
    store: store,
    resizeTabs: false,
    defaults: {
        bodyPadding: 10,
        layout: 'fit'
    },


    require: [
      'Cat3.view.fsm.components.SelectableButtons',
      'Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore'
    ],

    titleTpl: function(info) {
        return '<img src="resources/images/cards/operator/' +  info.status + '/' + info.name + '.png">';
    },

    listeners: {
        render: function(p) {
            var tabpanel = this;

            this.store.data.items.forEach(function(item, index) {
                item.data.status = index === 0 ? 'active' : 'passive';
                var buttons = new Cat3.view.fsm.components.SelectableButtons();
                tabpanel.add(Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                    id: 'tab-' + index,
                    title: tabpanel.titleTpl(item.data),
                    items: [ buttons ],
                    cls: item.data.status,
                    info: item.data,
                    listeners: {
                        render: function(p) {
                            console.log('render');
                        }
                    }
                }));
            });
            tabpanel.setActiveTab(0);
        },

        tabchange: function(tabPanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
            newCard.info.status = 'active';
            newCard.setTitle(this.titleTpl(newCard.info));
            newCard.items.items[0].refresh();

            if (oldCard) {
                oldCard.info.status = 'passive';
                oldCard.setTitle(this.titleTpl(oldCard.info));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

SelectableButtons Store:

```
var ImageModel = Ext.define('ImageModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
       {name: 'type', type: 'string'},
       {name: 'status', type: 'string'},
    ]
});

Ext.define('Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'ImageModel',
    data: [
        {name: 'amena', type: 'operator', status: 'passive'},
        {name: 'movistar', type: 'operator', status: 'passive'},
        {name: 'orange', type: 'operator', status: 'passive'},
        {name: 'simyo', type: 'operator', status: 'passive'},
        {name: 'yoigo', type: 'operator', status: 'passive'},
        {name: 'vodafone', type: 'operator', status: 'passive'}
    ],
    listeners: {
        datachanged: function() {
            console.log('store data changed');
        }
    }
});
```

All works fine, but when I select a button of SelectableButtons (one tab), the same button of each tab changes its status, and only the one selected of the active tab has to change. Any ideas why? I've checked each store is created separately and that each store has a different id.

Comment: probably problem caused by defining data along with "Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore", try to use loadData method after creating "Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore". ex. (inside Cat3.view.fsm.components.SelectableButtons), initComponent: function(){ var store = Ext.create('Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore'); store.loadData(<data here>)}

Comment: Wow, after five hours of don't knowing what was going on, that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, for a better guess I'd need to see it working best at http://fiddle.sencha.com:

If "select one selects all", my first idea is that all buttons are just one button referred to from all places. One instance with different names.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that Sencha had a Fiddle page, and seems very useful! About the answer, finally the first comment did work.

Answer (score -1):

Notice the line on your `Cat3.view.fsm.components.SelectableButtons` view:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore');
    ...
}
```

You might wanna change it to

```
initComponent: function() {
    var store = new Ext.create('Cat3.view.fsm.data.ButtonsStore');
    ...
}
```

This will create a new instance of `Data Store` for your view.